# which-function-mode is broken after first ggtags-find-tag-dwim call

Tags: which-function-mode

after first `ggtags-find-tag-dwim` call I see the current tag where I saw the current function...
How I can avoid this?
I do not want to see in header current tag (where cursor is)

Normally `which-function-mode` show in header name of the function where cursor is located.

f.e.  `[main()]` if my cursor is in main function. It worked for a long time until I tried to use `ggtags-mode` and `helm-gtags` modes. It seems those modes override this header and show current tag. f.e. `assert()` if cursor in line `assert(x>20);`
I do not need such a new behavior...

Comment: This a bit too concise for me to understand what it is you've done and what you saw happen.  Please clarify what you've done, what you expected to happen, and what happened instead.

Comment: @Stefan I hope it is more clear now...